# PHP boolean to string with modification & a condition

Tags: php, boolean, conditional-statements

When `echo`ing a boolean (true or false), PHP converts it to `1` or `<nothing>` and displays it. e.g.:

```
$x = true; echo $x; //displays: 1
$x = false; echo $x; //displays: <nothing>
```

**My Question:** Is there a PHP function (if not how to code it) which can display exactly "true" or "false" (and not 1 or nothing), if a variable is a boolean *otherwise* just display as PHP would normally display it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it can be easily coded like this:

```
function var_to_str($in)
{
   if(is_bool($in))
   {
      if($in)
         return "true";
      else
         return "false";
   }
   else
      return $in;
}

//Test it now
echo var_to_str("this is string") . PHP_EOL;
echo var_to_str(123) . PHP_EOL;
echo var_to_str(true) . PHP_EOL;
echo var_to_str(false) . PHP_EOL;
```

This outputs:

```
this is string  
123  
true  
false
```

Answer (score 8):

I've just been looking to do this but needed to to it inline without a function so I just used :

```
echo(is_bool($x) ? ($x ? "true":"false"):$x);
```

Not the easiest to read but gets the job done!

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace(array(0, 1), array("No", "Yes"), str_pad(headers_sent(), 1, "0"))
```

I used `headers_sent()` just as a BOOLEAN variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, found this question and the answer was not quite what I needed, so I worked out this:

array_pop(array_keys(array('FALSE' => false,'TRUE' => true), [bool]))

to simply get a printed (echoed) string value for a [bool], replacing [bool] with a variable you know to be a bool.

Thought it might help others who find this question....

Comment: That would work, but a serious performance hit. Better write a function that returns the appropriate string for the value.